# Field repository required a bean of type that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, repository

service and repository but when i try to run the project i get the error:

```
Field foodRepository in com.bif.auth.service.FoodService required a bean of type 'com.bif.auth.repo.FoodRepository' that could not be found.
```

My model:

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Data
@Table(name="food")
public class Food {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="calorie")
    private double calorie;
    @Column(name="protein")
    private double protein;
    @Column(name="carb")
    private double carb;
    @Column(name="fat")
    private double fat;
    @Column(name="quantity_enum")
    private String quantityEnum;
    @Column(name="quantity")
    private double quantity;
```

My service:

```
import com.bif.auth.repo.FoodRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class FoodService {

  @Autowired
  FoodRepository foodRepository;
}
```

and my Repo:

```
package com.bif.auth.repo;

import com.bif.auth.models.Food;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface FoodRepository extends CrudRepository<Food,Long> {
}
```

I am using the following code sql to create table in the postgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS food (
                      id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                      name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                      calorie DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
                      protein DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
                      carb DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
                      fat DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
                      quantity_enum VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                      quantity DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL
);
```

When i try to run my application i get the error and i don't know where it comes from any need is welcomed
thanks

Comment: Check if your `FoodRepository` class is visible to Spring. Make sure it is in package inside your `@ComponentScan` (or related composite annotation) scope. Also, there are some tools to debug Spring bootstrap - search for them on the internet.

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using? You are also using the wrong `@Id` for your entities, it should come from the JPA package you are using not Spring Data. Additional Pro-tip don't use `@Data` with JPA entities (see https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/).